# In The Bourne Ultimatum, how was Jason able to enter the USA on his Brazilian passport?

Tags: realism, the-bourne-ultimatum

In *The Bourne Ultimatum* (2007), towards the end of the movie, Jason enters the U.S.A. (from Tangier, Morocco) using his Brazilian passport (Gilberto de Piento). How could he have done this realistically in-universe?

Here are my problems with this.

Suspension of belief aside, as realistically possible in-universe:

1. How does Jason enter the U.S.A. on his Brazilian passport? From what I can see now, Brazilian passport holders need a visa to enter the U.S.A., and U.S.A. visas require an appointment so I assume it was the same in 2006. There are no U.S. consulates or embassies in Tangier and it can take months to get any type of visa and it seems that he managed to get to the US in weeks if not days. All that aside: he would still need an interview first to get a visa (unless rules were different in 2006). Which brings me to my second question:
2. Is Jason only "wanted" by the secret unsanctioned/corrupt division of the CIA (ie the CIA proper has no issue with him? At first I thought this could be the case since Pamela Landy obviously has no problems with him, until I remember that Ezra Kramer is the head of the CIA in its entirety, ie the director, and he obviously has a problem with Jason), or does US immigration know about him too? If so, would he not have been caught at the embassy when going for an interview?
3. In *The Bourne Ultimatum*, Noah Vosen ordered a stop on Niel Daniels' passport (although it was too late). The question here is then: Can the CIA order stops on passports/influence who is let through immigration and who is not? If so, why didn't he simply put a stop on all of Jason's known passports? Even if the Brazilian passport "never went to the grid", the people at the CIA, both Pamela Landy and Noah Vosen's team should have at least known it existed, if not, in Noah's case, not looking for it.

My solutions to the issues are:

1. He could have gone to Rabat (where there is a U.S. embassy) in Morocco to get the visa/appointment and for the sake of a movie, we just pretend the visa was obtained quickly in days or weeks rather than months.
2. Maybe the U.S. immigration has no issues with Jason Bourne (is there proof of this somewhere in the movies?) and so does not know he is wanted by the CIA so that when he goes for an interview with his Brazilian passport, as far as US embassy people know, he is Gilberto de Piento and approves Gilberto de Piento a visa.
3. No solution. Additionally number 2 above gives more questions: if the CIA can influence immigration, why not just tell immigration all of Jason's aliases and ban him from getting a visa on any passport/entry to the US at all?

Is this all questioning the premise of the movie too much (ie, the answer is simply "It's a movie, just watch and accept it") or is there a plausible in-universe explanation?

Comment: If you can fake a passport, why can't you fake a visa?

Comment: Because - there is nothing in the movies to suggest Jason made fake passports. In-universe he even said to Marie in Identity that "these [passports] are real."

Comment: B1/B2 visa for BR passports are valid for 10 years, no? I haven't watched this movie, is it possible that he already had the visa way before the movie events?

Comment: @Luciano Actually this is an acceptable plausible situation and one I have not thought of. Thanks. You should consider putting that as an answer.

Comment: The passport was generated by Bourne's handlers at the CIA. He and they are fully aware of its existence and there's no obvious reason why they couldn't just put a flag on it that says "let him in".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jason Bourne as Gilberto di Piento and passports](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32395/jason-bourne-as-gilberto-di-piento-and-passports)

Comment: [Unfortunately, your question has been closed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/122212/timeline). You have the option to appeal for the reopening of this question and/or seek feedback from the community on [meta].

Comment: It looks like the question was closed for lack of focus, which isn't an unfair assessment.  You're asking many questions in one.  Instead, split out each distinct question into a separate post.  You can edit to cut out your extraneous questions and then write them up separately.

Answer (score 5):

Why wasn't his passport caught? The di Piento passport has never been used and hence isn't on the watchlist of identities that Vosen's people are looking out for, as stated [in this answer to another question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43785/19762).

How did he enter the USA from Tangiers without a visa or how did he get a visa so quickly?

B1/B2 visas for [Brazillian passports](https://www.ivisa.com/usa/b1b2-visa) [are valid for 10 years](https://www.ivisa.com/usa/blog/the-b1b2-visa-duration#us-b1/b2-visa-validity-period), so he could've had it from the moment the passport was generated (assuming it was less than 10 years earlier).

Comment: Thank you for this. This question was closed, not by me, so unfortunately no new answers are possible but I wanted to add that even if the passport hasn't been used before, as another commenter said, the CIA handlers made it, so they should know about it regardless. Thus: why not just stop the passport like they did with Niel Daniels.

Comment: They didn't stop it because they weren't looking for this ID, check the other answer I linked to.

Comment: You can edit your question as per comments suggestion and it might be voted for reopening